# C++ Read 1 Bit From Memory?

Tags: c++, memory, byte, memory-address, bit

So looking in debugger I have found that i need to check if 1 bit is set to a certain value.

For example lets say at this memory address `0x12345` holds these four bytes `01008100`, how would I go about checking if ONLY `8` is right there in that exact point? Sorry I am at a lack of words to use, I am not even sure how to really explain. But for example if I wanted to check if `8` was right there in that exact position in those bytes posted above my first guess would be to try something like this

```
if(*(char*)(0x12345 + 0x2) == 8)
{
    //ok
}
```

But this obivously won't work because it will read the value as `0x81`, I need to ONLY read if the `8` is there and ignore all other bits in front or behind it. Hopefully this question was worded in a way that at least someone will understand my question. Thank you for reading have a good day.

Comment: For the sake of wording, `8` is not 1 bit in this case, it is one figure of the hexadecimal representation of your byte.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a bitwise AND (`&`) to test individual bits, e.g.

```
if ((*(char*)(0x12345 + 0x2) & 0x80) == 0x80)
{
    //ok
}
```

Note that the AND operation *masks out* the bits you are not interested in, e.g.

```
0x12345 + 0x2:    10000001    ; 0x81

AND with 0x80:    10000000    ; 0x80
```

Comment: should be `& 0x80) == 0x80`

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you want to check if a particular bit in your 4 bytes value is set or not.

Assuming that you want to check the bit on a stream of bytes, and NOT on a 32 bits value, then I would use something similar to what you specified, but I would use a bitwise and operator:

```
if((*(std::uint8_t*)(0x12345 + 0x2) & 0x80) != 0)
{
    // the bit is set
}
```

If you are trying to check the bit in a uint32 value, then you have to consider the endianness of the machine you are working with (high or low bit endian).

Fortunately, if you specify the right data type then the machine will take care of that for you.

```
// Note: 0x12345 is a fictional address, not properly aligned on some architectures
if((*(std::uint32_t*)0x12345 & 0x00008000) != 0) 
{
    // the bit is set
}
```

Comment: @Raul R: Thanks for the feedback. I moved the comment to make it more visible